# How to display Wordpress search results?

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I've spent a lot of time figuring out why my search is not working in my custom made template. So far I was able to figure out how to include searchform.php file in my header, created search.php file which is currently empty (so at the moment when I search for something I get redirected to a blank page and I think I definitely need something in search.php file to make it work), I was reading all around Wordpress codex but could not find a solution, only useful information I found was this.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Can you suggest what need's to be done in order to display results of a search? is there a special query, function etc? I really can't find it anywhere.

my **searchform.php** file in case you need it.

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" id="search-form" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="type your search" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='type your search'"
    onfocus="if(this.value=='type your search')this.value=''" />
    <input type="hidden" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as [this other question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800675/wordpress-not-displaying-search-results)

Comment: @DamienPirsy It was, I deleted previous question as it turned out confusing for people to understand, I made this one simpler.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Basically, you need to include the Wordpress loop in your search.php template to loop through the search results and show them as part of the template.

Below is a very basic example from [The WordPress Theme Search Template and Page Template](http://themeshaper.com/2012/11/06/the-wordpress-theme-search-template-and-page-template/) over at ThemeShaper.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Search Results pages.
 *
 * @package Shape
 * @since Shape 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

        <section id="primary" class="content-area">
            <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <header class="page-header">
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'shape' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .page-header -->

                <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

            </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
        </section><!-- #primary .content-area -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 59):

you need to include the Wordpress loop in your search.php
this is example

**search.php** template file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
$s=get_search_query();
$args = array(
                's' =>$s
            );
    // The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        _e("<h2 style='font-weight:bold;color:#000'>Search Results for: ".get_query_var('s')."</h2>");
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
           $the_query->the_post();
                 ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </li>
                 <?php
        }
    }else{
?>
        <h2 style='font-weight:bold;color:#000'>Nothing Found</h2>
        <div class="alert alert-info">
          <p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.</p>
        </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks. it works for me. i want to also count number for search result. like 4 search result found . any idea how ?

Comment: new code like pic add new variabe: 
this is picture :    http://i.imgur.com/8NgI15D.png

Comment: To check the result count use this: <? global $wp_query;
$total_results = $wp_query->found_posts;  ?> . Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Comment: is it safe to use output in this way without checking?

Comment: @RodinOleksandr You can modify the code and add a verification code as you wish

Answer (score 18):

I am using `searchform.php` and `search.php` files as already mentioned, but here I provide the actual code.

[Creating a Search Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) `codex` page helps here and `#Creating_a_Search_Page_Template` shows the search query.

In my case I pass the `$search_query` arguments to the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) `Class` (which can determine if is search query!).  I then run [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) to display the post information I want to, which in my case is the [the_permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) and `the_title`.

Search box form:

```
<form class="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" role="search">
  <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search …', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" />
  <button type="submit" role="button" class="btn btn-default right"/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search white"></span></button>
</form>
```

`search.php` template file:

```
<?php
    global $query_string;
    $query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
    $search_query = array();

    foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
      $query_split = explode("=", $string);
      $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
    } // foreach

    $the_query = new WP_Query($search_query);
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    ?>
    <!-- the loop -->

    <ul>    
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>   
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Check whether your template in `theme` folder contains `search.php` and `searchform.php` or not.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress include tags, categories and taxonomies in search results

This code is taken from http://atiblog.com/custom-search-results/

Some functions here are taken from twentynineteen theme.Because it is made on this theme.

This code example will help you to include tags, categories or any custom taxonomy in your search. And show the posts contaning these tags or categories.

You need to modify your search.php of your theme to do so.

```
<?php
$search=get_search_query();
$all_categories = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'category','hide_empty' => true) ); 
$all_tags = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'post_tag','hide_empty' => true) );
//if you have any custom taxonomy
$all_custom_taxonomy = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy-slug','hide_empty' => true) );

$mcat=array();
$mtag=array();
$mcustom_taxonomy=array();

foreach($all_categories as $all){
$par=$all->name;
if (strpos($par, $search) !== false) {
array_push($mcat,$all->term_id);
}
}

foreach($all_tags as $all){
$par=$all->name;
if (strpos($par, $search) !== false) {
array_push($mtag,$all->term_id);
}
}

foreach($all_custom_taxonomy as $all){
$par=$all->name;
if (strpos($par, $search) !== false) {
array_push($mcustom_taxonomy,$all->term_id);
}
}

$matched_posts=array();
$args1= array( 'post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => -1,'tax_query' =>array('relation' => 'OR',array('taxonomy' => 'category','field' => 'term_id','terms' =>$mcat),array('taxonomy' => 'post_tag','field' => 'term_id','terms' =>$mtag),array('taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy','field' => 'term_id','terms' =>$mcustom_taxonomy)));

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args1 );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$the_query->the_post();
array_push($matched_posts,get_the_id());
//echo '<li>' . get_the_id() . '</li>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
} else {

}

?>
<?php
// now we will do the normal wordpress search
$query2 = new WP_Query( array( 's' => $search,'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
if ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
$query2->the_post();
array_push($matched_posts,get_the_id());
}
wp_reset_postdata();
} else {

}
$matched_posts= array_unique($matched_posts);
$matched_posts=array_values(array_filter($matched_posts));
//print_r($matched_posts);
?>

<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query3 = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'=>'any','post__in' => $matched_posts ,'paged' => $paged) );
if ( $query3->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query3->have_posts() ) {
$query3->the_post();
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'excerpt' );
}
twentynineteen_the_posts_navigation();
wp_reset_postdata();
} else {

}
?>
```